# Responsive design bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i must realize this

[goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT9jm.jpg)

3 col with background and into col 2 div : one for png (il box - classi - open gym) one for text !

I've problem with responsive situation, when change resolution change all elements !!!

this is my code :

```
<div class="row full">
        <div class="col-sm-4 box-home nopadding">
        <img src="<?php the_field('immagine_il_box'); ?>" class="img-responsive img-box-home">

            <div class="title" style="background-image: url('/crossfitpontedera/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/bottone-ilbox.png');"></div>
            <div class="description" id="descr-one">
            <h2><?php the_field('titolo_il_box'); ?></h2>
            <p><?php the_field('descrizione_il_box'); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 box-home" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field('immagine_classi'); ?>');">
            <div class="title" style="background-image: url('/crossfitpontedera/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/bottone-classi.png');"></div>
            <div class="description" id="descr-two">
            <h2><?php the_field('titolo_classi'); ?></h2>
            <p><?php the_field('descrizione_classi'); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 box-home" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field('immagine_open_gym'); ?>');">
            <div class="title" style="background-image: url('/crossfitpontedera/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/bottone-opengym.png');"></div>
            <div class="description" id="descr-three">
            <h2><?php the_field('titolo_open_gym'); ?></h2>
            <p><?php the_field('descrizione_open_gym'); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

ok, there are various classes for h1 and p etc, but the problem is this

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC0d2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As you want to have responsiveness for all screen size and you want to achieve same layout for all screen size, you have to use `class="col-xs-4"`.

When you are using `class="col-sm-4"` you lose the responsiveness below 768px.
That is why you are experiencing such a problem.

**Here is an example see how it works for all screen sizes**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           </head>
<body >
  
              <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: white; color: black">
        

           
            <h2>some text</h2>
            <p>some text</p>
            </div>
       

        <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: green; color: blue;">
            
            <h2>some text</h2>
            <p>some text</p>
            </div>
       

        <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color: yellow; color: red;">
           
            <h2>some text</h2>
            <p>some text</p>
            </div>
        
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Your desired layout should look like this**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           </head>
<body >
  <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg'); height: 400px;">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1" style="background-color: white; color: black; height: 100px; ">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style=" height: 100px;">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" style="background-color: green; color: blue; height: 200px;">
        </div>
        </div>

            </div>
       

         <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg'); height: 400px;">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1" style="background-color: white; color: black; height: 100px; ">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style=" height: 100px;">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" style="background-color: green; color: blue; height: 200px;">
        </div>
        </div>

            </div>
       

         <div class="col-xs-4 " style="background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg'); height: 400px;">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1" style="background-color: white; color: black; height: 100px; ">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style=" height: 100px;">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" style="background-color: green; color: blue; height: 200px;">
        </div>
        </div>

            </div>
        
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note**

[This is a good place to start learning about bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Hope this helps!